# Excel VBA webpage dropdown list activation

Tags: html, vba, dropdown

I have a webpage I am trying to interact with via Excel VBA and I am having problems getting it to respond to my coded requests.

There is a dropdown list on the page and it only changes if the mouse is used to click it. Interestingly, when I watch the HTML code (F12) and do the initial mouse click on the dropdown menu, nothing changes or appears to affect the HTML code. However, I am able to change the dropdown selection via my code, but the page does not recognize change or update accordingly.

I've read some things in these forums about some webpages that require mouse input, but it seems like a "Click()" command should work/function the same.

Unfortunately, the website can only be accessed by authorized folks, but I cut the portion of the applicable code here:

```html
<select
    class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty"
    name="DataSource"
    ng-model="reportBuilder.selectedDataSource"
    ng-options="o.key as o.value for o in reportBuilder.dataSources"
    ng-change="reportBuilder.onDataSourceChage()"
    aria-invalid="false"
>
    <option label="Aircraft" value="number:0" selected="selected">Aircraft</option>
    <option label="Flight" value="number:1">Flight</option>
    <option label="Ground Operation" value="number:2">Ground Operation</option>
    <option label="Lifing" value="number:3">Lifing</option>
    <option label="Milestones Completed" value="number:4">Milestones Completed</option>
    <option label="PACE" value="number:5">PACE</option>
</select>
```

Here is my code for accessing the "DataSource" dropdown menu:

```
Dim dropdown As Object
Dim elem As Object

Set dropdown = IE.document.getElementsByName("DataSource").getElementsByTagName("options")
For Each elem In dropdown
    If elem.lable = "Flight" Then
        elem.Selected = True
        IE.document.getElementByName("DataSource")(0).Click
    End If
Next elem
```

This code properly selects the "Flight" option from the dropdown menu and places it in the webpage window, and the code also accepts the "Click" command, but nothing changes on the webpage. I see the "ng-change" field in the "DataSource" element, but I am not sure I can interact with it via VBA. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I found this page, but I am not sure how to use the "querrySelector()" command as my element does not have an ID like it did in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673070/dropdown-menus-with-vba?rq=1

Comment: If the code changes the option value but it is not registered as updated you likely need to attach an onchange event to the parent select (before selecting option) and dispatch that after you select your option.

Comment: For the option you can use `ie.document.querySelector("option[label='Flight']").Selected = True` The parent select with `ie.document.querySelector("select[name='DataSource']")` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: @QHarr, the selection of Flight worked just like my previous code, but the second querrySelector line: IE.document.querySelector("select[name='DataSource']"), worked in the code (stepping trough) but still didn't change the page. Do I need to select something else?

Comment: That is where you need to attach the html change event https://stackoverflow.com/a/58545643/6241235

Comment: Awesome thanks @QHarr worked beautifully!