# Excel VBA: IE date selection/manipluation that normally uses mouse commands via a datepicker-popup

Tags: html, excel, vba, calendar, selector

I am trying to manipulate a date field on an IE webpage via Excel VBA that normally uses mouse commands via a datepicker-popup. I am able to access and directly change the date text, but that "breaks" the HTML code and the site no longer works correctly, nor does the site refresh to the date I input. Here is the website HTML code:

```html
    <div class="col-4 text-center daily-sched-header-date">
    <h2 title="Select Date" show-button-bar="false" 
      datepicker-options="main.pickerOptions" 
      ng-change="main.selectedSchedule()" is-open="main.opened" 
      ng-model="main.pickerDate" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" 
      ng-click="main.opened = true" popup-placement="bottom" 
      class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty 
      ng-valid-date ng-touched" 
      role="button" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" style="">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true">
    </i>&nbsp;Jun 16, 2021</h2>

    <div uib-datepicker-popup-wrap="" ng-model-options="ngModelOptions" 
         ng-model="date" ng-change="dateSelection(date)" 
         template-url="uib/template/datepickerPopup/popup.html" 
          class="ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-date-disabled ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" 
          aria-invalid="false" style="">
    <!-- ngIf: isOpen -->
    </div></div>
```

I access the date text via the following Excel VBA code:

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("col-4 text-center daily-sched-header-date")(0).textContent = MonthName(mo, True) & " " & dy & ", " & yr
```

I can see the ng-change="dateSelection(date)" selector under the "ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-date-disabled ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" class in the HTML code, but I'm not sure how to properly access/manipulate it. I believe that is the key to correctly changing the date on the webpage and getting it to refresh with the correct date. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is there a public url?

Comment: @QHarr, unfortunately, no, the website is not public, it is behind a firewall.  However, you have helped me in the past with this same website at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67300334/excel-vba-webpage-dropdown-list-activation.  I thought perhaps something similar to the querySelector() might work and then dispatching an event.  Thoughts?